# How to correctly implement I18n in Blacklight for field labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, blacklight

The docs are sketchy on how to do it properly. I tried this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  before_action :set_locale
  def set_locale
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale = params.delete(:locale) || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

And this suffices for a lot of things; however, my fields are configured like this (following the Blacklight guide):

```
class CatalogController < ApplicationController
  include Blacklight::Catalog

  configure_blacklight do |config|
    # ...
    config.add_facet_field 'date', label: 'Date', single: false
    # ...
  end
end
```

This configuration happens before the request is processed, so if I try to use `I18n.t('Date')` for `label`, it will not respond to changes in locale, and will always serve the labels corresponding to the default locale.

What is the "correct" way to do this?

**EDIT:** Found the solution for the individual fields. Still searching for the "proper" solution for the search fields (`config.add_search_field`). It seems those are just displaying their `label` if present, and `#labelize`-d `key` if not. As a quick stop-gap measure, I made this class:

```
class Localized
  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end

  def to_s
    I18n.t(key)
  end
end
```

and configured the search field with

```
... label: Localized.new('blacklight.search.general.all_fields')
```

Comment: When you do `include Blacklight::Catalog` you change the ancestor's chain for `CatalogController `, which would typically be `CatalogController  -> Blacklight::Catalog -> ApplicationController`, so when `set_locale` before action callback is called, it gets executed after `configure_backlight` method. Probably moving before action `set_locale` to `CatalogController` will fix it.

Comment: @Surya: Just tried, still stuck at `en.Date`. I've verified (by the advanced debugging technique of `puts "YO"`) that `configure_blacklight` block is only  ever executed once (at the first request), not once per request.

Comment: Looks like it has to invoked [via helper methods](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/blob/1cfced619f9582a0655d7151a5ec1c01dc99db97/spec/helpers/blacklight/search_history_constraints_helper_behavior_spec.rb#L85-L103): [`render_search_to_s_filters`](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/blob/291d0c08bb58c10bba9f2b35c9030945fabf0d53/app/helpers/blacklight/search_history_constraints_helper_behavior.rb#L30), pass `:f` key with respect to locale that is selected.

Comment: @Surya: Not quite the answer, but it gave me the vital clue. Thank you!

Comment: @Amadan Where did you add the Localized class? I am struggling with a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317700/page-needs-to-be-refreshed-after-switching-locale-for-blacklight-label-to-transl). The `configure_blacklight` method gets executed before the `set_locale` method, and moving `set_locale` to `CatalogController` did not work for me either. I would really appreciate your help in this. Thank you!

Comment: @humairatasnim: `lib/localized.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Surya, I saw where to look. The helper methods are already being invoked by the Blacklight's default templates, as long as one uses the correct keys. So, to localise the `date` field label in English, one needs the key named `en.blacklight.search.fields.date`.