# Page needs to be refreshed after switching locale for Blacklight label to translate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, blacklight

I am trying to create an Arabic version of a Rails app which is based on Blacklight. Here's the problem I am facing:

When I switch the language, everything translates perfectly EXCEPT the Blacklight labels. It's only when I refresh the page that the labels get translated.

This is the label I want to display: "ترتيب حسب عام" (Translation: Sort by Year)

But this is what I am getting currently: "Year ترتيب حسب"

The same issue happens when switching back to English from Arabic - the label displays in Arabic until I refresh the page.

This is what my Blacklight configuration looks like:

```
class CatalogController < ApplicationController
  include Blacklight::Catalog

  configure_blacklight do |config|
    # ...
    config.add_sort_field 'pub_date_sort desc, title_sort asc', :label => I18n.t('sortby.year')
    # ...
  end
end
```

Here's how I am setting the locale in my Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 before_filter :set_locale
 def set_locale
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end

 # ...
end
```

I am not sure what's happening and I would really appreciate your help in this.

Comment: you can set the arabic locale in `rails console` and check the value of `I18n.t('sortby.year')`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yes, the value of `I18n.t('sortby.year')` is showing up correctly. It shows up correctly on the page as well once the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem that the correct locale is not taken into account on the first page render lies in the fact that `configure_blacklight` is a **class method** that is run when the `CatalogController` class gets interpreted, i.e. **before the `before_filter` for locale switching is run**. (Actually I don't quite understand why it actually works after a page reload as I would expect the before filter always to be run *after* setting the blacklight configuration.)

Nevertheless, support for I18n-ing search and sort fields **has recently been added to the Blacklight project** - see [Pull Request #1566](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/pull/1566). It seems that this change is not part of a public release yet so you need to use the `master` branch version to be able to actually use this feature.

Blacklight in general, as well as this new feature, [uses Rails I18n API](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/wiki/Internationalization) for localized labels so instead of manually specifying the labels you should use the I18n dictionary YAML files (see [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for more info and options).

In your particular case, the label for a sort field is [looked up](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/pull/1566/files#diff-498a6f1c331e8b6eeabe770c99507587R24) under the following key:

```
"blacklight.search.fields.sort.#{key}"
```

where `key` is the value of the first parameter that you pass to the sort field definition. Thus, for your particular field, you should define something like the following in your dictionaries:

```
en:    
  blacklight:
    search:
      fields:
        sort:
          pub_date_sort desc, title_sort asc: "Sort by Year"
```

(this would be for the English version). I am amazed that YAML has no problems with spaces and commas in the key definitions, but indeed I tested that such key works OK when used by the I18n API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using an older version of Blacklight which does not have support for localized labels, so this does not work for me.

Comment: I see, I'm a bit skeptical that it will be possible on an older version of Blacklight, but perhaps I'm wrong and someone will find out. Good luck!